# simple email causes stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sendmail, actionmailer

I have mailer:

```
class AdminMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "pejottest@gmail.com" 
  def message
    mail(:to => "pejottest@gmail.com",:subject => "test")
  end
end
```

When I i use them from the controller :

```
def create
  AdminMailer.message.deliver
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Then I got

```
SystemStackError in EmailsController#create
stack level too deep
```

Without any trace and so on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you'll find the `message` method is [reserved by Action Mailer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L460). I would recommend calling your method different from this to prevent this conflict.

Thanks to Ben Lee in the comments for pointing out where this comes from.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L442